# Export report into csv format using reporting service?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I used to default export option in reporting service to export the report in CSV format.

my table result is

```
         sno   sname     values          method
         1      aaa       123,124,145     aa
         2      bbb       234,454,565     bb
         3      ccc       454,511,455     cc
```

This table value i exported in csv format that time display wrong alignment...

```
         sno   sname     values        method          
         1      aaa       123           124        145     aa
         2      bbb       234           454        565     bb
         3      ccc       454           511        455     cc
```

is it possible to comma is no need to separate the value in csv....

plz help me soon....

Comment: comments like "plz help me soon...." will *not* encourage SO users to help you any faster.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cell holding the `values` field in the report designer, then check the Format property in the properties window - this will probably be set to something like `#,###` . To remove the commas from the values field, change the Format property to be `#` .